# How to Ping externally hosted server from Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I am connecting to a externally hosted MongoDB server from Heroku app. I need to test **latency** between my Heroku app and **MongoDB server**. I ran **Heroku bash** but '**ping**' command is not available there. My only purpose is to test **latency** between Heroku and MongoDB server.

Comment: Have you tried pinging from the MongoDB server to your Heroku server, or using another means to measure latency? For example, you could send a ping (or time a request) from your application code rather than relying on the system `ping` command. Also, this seems like a topic better suited for ServerFault (networking/admin questions) than StackOverflow (programming questions).

Comment: I'm actually also trying to run Heroku's system ping too, but indirectly, and I haven't been able to achieve it yet. With indirectly I mean I'm doing it from a rails app, using ruby's **net-ping** gem, and it seems that the system's **ping** is not available. Any update here please let me know!. Thanks!.

Answer (score 6):

Try this (needs node.js): https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-ping

```js
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.9040
~ $ npm install tcp-ping
tcp-ping@0.1.1 node_modules/tcp-ping
~ $ node
> var tcpp = require('tcp-ping');
undefined
> tcpp.ping({ address: 'www.heroku.com', port: 80 }, function(err, data) {
...     console.log(data);
... });
undefined
> { address: 'www.heroku.com',
  port: 80,
  attempts: 10,
  avg: 10.4436728,
  max: 31.421943,
  min: 4.133464,
  results:
   [ { seq: 0, time: 31.421943 },
     { seq: 1, time: 7.204108 },
     { seq: 2, time: 10.878877 },
     { seq: 3, time: 13.744017 },
     { seq: 4, time: 4.133464 },
     { seq: 5, time: 7.970543 },
     { seq: 6, time: 9.550277 },
     { seq: 7, time: 7.120228 },
     { seq: 8, time: 6.797261 },
     { seq: 9, time: 5.61601 } ] }

undefined
```

So, first install tcp-ping:

```js
~ $ npm install tcp-ping
```

Then, copy paste these into the Node REPL client:

```js
var tcpp = require('tcp-ping');
tcpp.ping({ address: 'www.heroku.com', port: 80 }, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```